# API LinkedIn - Error on getaccesstoken()

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I m trying to get access to the linkedin api but like a lot of people, fail everytime and have this following message of error :

> missing required parameters, includes an invalid parameter value, parameter more then once. : Unable to retrieve access token : appId or redirect uri does not match authorization code or authorization code expired

I've cheked the hosting server's timestamp and i revoke and create the token on the app admin before i launch the code (the faster i can due to the short life time of the authorization code given).

Here's my index file and just after the functions i use :

```
<?php
// VARS
define('API_KEY', 'xxxxxxxxxx');
define('API_SECRET', 'xxxxxxxxxx');
define('REDIRECT_URI', 'https://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
define('SCOPE', 'r_basicprofile');

session_name('linkedin');
session_start();

include('lib/functions.php');

// OAuth 2 Control Flow
if (isset($_GET['error'])) {
    // LinkedIn returned an error
    print $_GET['error'] . ': ' . $_GET['error_description'];
    exit;
} 

elseif (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    // User authorized your application
    getAccessToken();   
} 

else {
    if ((empty($_SESSION['expires_at'])) || (time() > $_SESSION['expires_at'])) {
        // Token has expired, clear the state
        $_SESSION = array();
    }
    if (empty($_SESSION['access_token'])) {
        // Start authorization process
        getAuthorizationCode();
   }
}

// Congratulations! You have a valid token. Now fetch your profile
$user = fetch('GET', '/v1/people/~:(firstName,lastName)');
print "Hello $user->firstName $user->lastName.";

?>
```

And the functions :

```
<?php

function getAuthorizationCode() {
    $params = array('response_type' => 'code',
            'client_id' => API_KEY,
            'scope' => SCOPE,
            'state' => uniqid('', true), // unique long string
            'redirect_uri' => REDIRECT_URI
    );

    // Authentication request
    $url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?'.http_build_query($params);

    // Needed to identify request when it returns to us
    $_SESSION['state'] = $params['state'];

    // Redirect user to authenticate
    header("Location: $url");
    exit;
}

function getAccessToken() {
    $params = array('grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
                'client_id' => API_KEY,
                'client_secret' => API_SECRET,
                'code' => $_GET['code'],
                'redirect_uri' => REDIRECT_URI
                );

    var_dump($params);    

    // Access Token request
    //$url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken?' . http_build_query($params);

    $url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken';

    $c = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST,true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($params));

    $response = curl_exec($c); // on execute la requete

    curl_close($c);

    // Native PHP object, please
    $token = json_decode($response);

    // Store access token and expiration time
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $token->access_token; // guard this!
    $_SESSION['expires_in']   = $token->expires_in; // relative time (in seconds)
    $_SESSION['expires_at']   = time() + $_SESSION['expires_in']; // absolute time

    // DEBUG //
    echo 'Retour get access token : </br>';
    var_dump($token);
    echo '</br>--------------------------</br></br>';
    // ! DEBUG //   

    return true;
}

function fetch($method, $resource, $body = '') {
    $params = array('oauth2_access_token' => $_SESSION['access_token'], 'format' => 'json');

    // Need to use HTTPS
    //$url = 'https://api.linkedin.com' . $resource . '?' . http_build_query($params);
    // Tell streams to make a (GET, POST, PUT, or DELETE) request

    $url = 'https://api.linkedin.com' . $resource;

    $c = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($params));

    $response = curl_exec($c);
    curl_close($c);

    // DEBUG //
    echo 'Retour fetch : </br>';
    var_dump($response); 
    echo '</br>--------------------------</br></br>';
    // ! DEBUG //

    // Native PHP object, please
    return json_decode($response);
}
?>
```

I tried many things but it never works. If someone see the issue tnaks a lot in advance.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem and my issue was caused by http_build_query() function, http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php

for some reason it tries to encode the parameters to build a query string that will be used by the Linkedin services, if you try to construct the string manually it will pass and it will work.

and actually I reached this page while searching to figure out if its a PHP version issue or maybe the function http_build_query() take in account some environment variables like encoding and locale settings.

not sure but this fixed my issue.